# Migrate a question

Tags: support, migration

I posted a question about geometric-probability: "Pioneer probe´s distance to another star on its way out of the galaxy" about the expected value of the least distance of a line through our galaxy to a star.

I got a contribution to my reputation but none to my question, which I would have preferred. Is it OK to migrate this question to Astronomy.SE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My advice: wait a week before you conclude a question will not be answered.

Then you can go ahead and try another part of SE.  Include the link to the older question when you post a new one.

Comment: And please include a link to the new question at the old one.

Comment: Thanks. I actually got an answer now, close to my guess.